# Why is an element in a tbody not moved above the table

Tags: css, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have added a filter component from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63143057/3546805) to the default Blazor weather example. It is working fine but the search input is displayed as if in the first row of the table.

```
<tbody>
  <FilterableTable Items=@forecasts GetFilterableText=@(item => item.Summary)>
    <tr>
      <td>@context.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
      <td>@context.TemperatureC</td>
      <td>@context.TemperatureF</td>
      <td>@context.Summary</td>
    </tr>
  </FilterableTable>
</tbody>
```

[See this fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/y5lz73w8) for the full code.

However when I put the resulting HTML in a JS fiddle with Bootstrap the input is displayed above the table.

```html
<tbody>
  <input class="filterbox" placeholder="filter">
  <tr>
    <td>06/05/2018</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>Freezing</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xvrj7sLz/) for the full code.

Am I missing something? Is there some bootstrap JS magic that moves the input that is missing in Blazor Server? And how could I move the search box above the table like it is in the JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the FilterableTable component contains the input element, and it, the FilterableTable component, is being rendered within the tbody html element. You should follow the design standards how to create a templated component. Here's a working example how to solve your issue. Note that I wrote this code very quickly, and that it may require some refinements.

### Index.razor

```
@page "/"
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <a class="btn" href="/create">
        <i class="oi oi-plus"></i>
        Add new item
    </a>

<FilterableTable Items=@forecasts GetFilterableText=@(item => item.Summary)>

    <TableHeader>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Temp. (C)</th>
            <th>Summary</th>
        </tr>

    </TableHeader>
 
     <RowTemplate>
                    <td>@context.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@context.TemperatureC</td>
                    <td>@context.Summary</td>
     </RowTemplate>
  
</FilterableTable>
}
@functions {
    WeatherForecast[] forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/sample-data/weather.json").ToString());
    }

    class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureF { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### FilterableTable.razor

```
@typeparam TItem

<p><input class="filterbox" @bind=Filter @bind:event="oninput" placeholder="filter" /></p>
<br />
<table class="table">
    <thead>
          @TableHeader
    </thead>
       
    <tbody>
        @foreach (TItem item in GetFilteredItems())
        {
            <tr>
               @RowTemplate(item)
         
            </tr>
         }
     </tbody>
</table>  

    @code {
        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment TableHeader { get; set; }

        [Parameter] public IEnumerable<TItem> Items { get; set; }
        [Parameter] public Func<TItem, string> GetFilterableText { get; set; }
        [Parameter] public RenderFragment<TItem> RowTemplate { get; set; }

        private string Filter;

        private static readonly Func<TItem, string> DefaultGetFilterableText = item => (item?.ToString() ?? string.Empty);

        private IEnumerable<TItem> GetFilteredItems()
        {
            Func<TItem, string> filterFunc = GetFilterableText ?? DefaultGetFilterableText;
            IEnumerable<TItem> result = (Items ?? Array.Empty<TItem>());
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Filter))
            {
                result = result.Where(x => (GetFilterableText(x) ?? string.Empty).Contains(Filter,
                  StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: okay making the whole table as template is of course a possibility. Guess I'm sticking to that, thank you.